# Is there a way to add depth map metadata to a jpg?

Tags: facebook, depth-of-focus

I want to make Facebook 3d photos directly from the computer. I understand how depth maps work and also how to extract them, but what about embedding them so you can make your own custom photos and just upload them without the need of an app?

I saw this example over PetaPixel:

https://petapixel.com/2018/10/23/photographer-turns-drone-shot-into-a-facebook-3d-photo/

In this minitutorial the guy joins the depth map with the jpg using an app called 'depth cam' ($3.99). Is there a tool so I can just get my jpg ready from the computer? I just want to upload it directly from the phone and forget about 'depth cam' , so I can work faster doing tests of which d-map nailed it.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking about. You are asking about a tool ("Is there a tool..."), but you want to do it "without the need of an app"? Sounds contradictory to me. Also, are you asking about _creating_ the depth map, or are you asking about how to embed a depth map into a flat JPEG, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Exiftool** to replace a pre-existing depth map with another one. This roundabout method is necessary because Exiftool cannot create new tags with embedded images.

1. Determine which tag likely contains the depth map.

   ```
   exiftool example.jpg | grep -i binary
   ```
2. Copy the tag to an image to which you want to add a depth map:

   ```
   exiftool -TagsFromFile example.jpg -Data image.jpg
   ```
3. Replace the depth map with a new one:

   ```
   exiftool '-Data<=depth-map.jpg' image.jpg
   ```

See also:

- [How to extract depth information from JPEG files?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86286/75526)

Comment: On Win11 I get the error "Warning: Sorry, Data is not writable"


> exiftool '-Data<=.\imgd.jpg' .\img.jpg
Warning: Sorry, Data is not writable
Nothing to do.

Comment: I guess its impossible to do unless you're replacing an existing depthmap. That is a strange limitation
https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=13681.0